# Total number divisor of form $4n+2$

Tags: number-theory

We have to find total number of divisor of form $4n+2$  of the number $2016$.

My attempt:

$2016=2^53^27^1$

So total number of divisors is  $6\times 3 \times 2=36$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(4n+2)|2016 \iff (2n+1)|1008$$
As $2n+1$ is odd, we need to find the number of odd divisors of $1008$. Note that this implies  $$(2n+1)|63=3^2 \times 7$$
So the number of divisors are $(2+1)(1+1)-1=5$ as $2n+1>1$.

Comment: Answer is given as5

Comment: @Koolman I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As $4n+2=2(2n+1)$

So, we actually need the number of odd divisors which is $(2+1)(1+1)$

Comment: Answer is given as 5

Comment: @Koolman, $$2X\{1,3,9\}X\{1,7\}=\{2,6,18,14,42,126\}$$